# Fetching one to many relationship data with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, one-to-many, relationship

I have a Core Data model with an entity called *SeasonInfo* that contains a bunch of attributes, one of which is an attribute called *year* (int 16).  *SeasonInfo* contains a one-to-many relationship to an entity called *GameInfo* (the relationship name defined in SeasonInfo is called *games*).

My populated database contains a bunch of seasons (one for every year)... then each season has a list of games - a bunch of games for each season.  *SeasonInfo* <---->> *GameInfo*

In my TableView contoller I use the following to access the *SeasonInfo* for a given year :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"SeasonInfo"      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set up the cell...
SeasonInfo *info = [seasonInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Put the Year as the Main title of the Row
yearLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",   info.year];
```

That seems to work great... but now I can't figure out how to access the games for a specific season.  From this table view, when I select a specific year, I'd like to pass an NSArray of games to another Table View controller... I know how to pass data between views, I just can't figure out how to populate the "gamesArray" before I transition to the Schedule View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to fetch the games for a specific season then you can use a predicate before you fetch such as (this only works for int 32, change string format specifier (%d) to whatever you need for an int16):

NSPredicate *equalPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"year == %d", year];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:equalPredicate];

If you don't want to do that and want everything to be collected then after your executeFetchRequest completes and you're in the successful completion block you will have been provided a NSArray * of results.

```
for (SeasonInfo * seasonInfo in results)
{
    if ([seasonInfo year] == <whatever year you want>)
    {
        //save this seasonInfo for use, this contains the games you're interested in.
    }
}
```

Afterwards, to get at the specific games in the seasonInfo

```
for (GameInfo * gameInfo in [seasonInfo games])
{
   // Do what's needed with the gameInfo.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've created the relationships properly in Core Data then you can just access the games relationship by it's property.

So info.games should return an NSSet of GameInfo for that SeasonInfo.

Comment: Thanks for the help... was able to get this working with this code: NSSet *gameSet = info.games;